# Plot both median and mean in Altair plot

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair

How can I plot both the mean and median in Altair, distinguished by a color encoding?

Below is my first attempt, but it doesn't include the legend, and does not seem like the most elegant way.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

mean = alt.Chart(source).mark_line(color='red', point=True).encode(
    x='Year',
    y='mean(Miles_per_Gallon)'
)

median = alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(
    x='Year',
    y='median(Miles_per_Gallon)'
)

mean+median
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can best be done with an [Aggregate Transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform.html#aggregate-transforms) to compute the aggregates, followed by a [Fold Transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform.html#fold-transform) to allow the two columns to be used in a single encoding:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

alt.Chart(source).transform_aggregate(
    mean='mean(Miles_per_Gallon)',
    median='median(Miles_per_Gallon)',
    groupby=['Year']
).transform_fold(
    ['mean', 'median'],
    as_=['aggregate', 'value']
).mark_line().encode(
    x='Year',
    y='value:Q', 
    color='aggregate:N',
)
```

[image]